# Can I send push notifications to users of one app, while customers enter data in another app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Basically, I want to create two apps: one would be device specific and other app will be with the owner of a particular group. I want the device specific, customizable app to be used by customers to input their views or suggestions.
Once the customer sends in any negative feedback **(1/5,2/5)** (scores will be there for categories like surrounding neatness, quality of service, etc), the  owner of this general app should receive a notification and be able to contact the customer.
So, how can I push a notification to one app when data is entered into a different app? Any tutorials?

Comment: unless devices you are using are jailbroken, unfortunately what you are asking is not possible. Apple Notifications are app specific. Maybe you can come up with some custom client server architecture of your own that could accomplish that

Comment: Of course it's possible. It just requires a server side component to mediate.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but not exactly simple.  For starters, as mentioned in the comment, you won't be able to use the Apple Push Notification Service, but rather some server-side component.  I have used [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) and its iOS compliment [SignalR-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) in the past and it works great under similar circumstances. The details of how to set this up are beyond the scope of this posting, however both projects are open-source and well supported so there is a strong community of users who can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge question and I don't think you will find a single tutorial that covers everything that is necessary. But basically, you need a server that both apps talk to (but this sort of app requires a server anyway so that shouldn't be a problem.)

The customer app will tell the server when a user sends negative feedback. When the server gets that message, it sends a push notification to the "owner" device.

This could probably be done with Parse.com...

Comment: Yeah I am gonna use Parse.com. Can you please help to find any tutorial for sending a notification from Parse.com to the owner's app. Is it possible ?

Comment: Check out this: https://parse.com/questions/how-to-send-push-notification-to-a-specific-device-without-creating-channels